# "Di fronte a" means "opposite" and "in front of"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, difference

In English, the prepositions "opposite" and "in front of" have a subtle difference:

- opposite: in a position facing someone or something but with something between both (eg street, river, table)
- in front of: close to the front of something or someone

Therefore, one would usually say "I am opposite the building" if he/she is on the other side of the street and "I am in front of the building" if he/she is on the same side of the street.

I have learned that "di fronte a" means "opposite". Can it also mean "in front of"? For instance, would I use it if I am standing on the same side of the street of a building? Word Reference dictionary says [so](https://www.wordreference.com/enit/in%20front%20of), but I would like to confirm it with native speakers.

Comment: No, you'd say _davanti a_. There is an alarming number of question originated by wrong or questionable online learning tools. Then again, anything that prompts a desire to learn more is fine...

Comment: @DaG: Could you write an answer based on what you have said in your comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sense “close to the front of something or someone” is mostly expressed in Italian by [*davanti*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/davanti). “I am in front of the building”, meaning on the same side of the street, is simply *Sono/sto davanti all'edificio*.

Notice that *davanti* needs the preposition *a* (*davanti al ristorante*) or a pronoun in a “dative” form (*se mi stai davanti non vedo nulla*). In archaic or poetic language, you can find it without *a*; for instance, a famous poem by Giosue Carducci is titled *Davanti San Guido*.